# How to make our selected value displayed in dropdown in html?

Tags: html, dropdown

I have a dropdown,code as follows:

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
    @if (Model.Period == 0 || Model.Period == null)
    {
        <select name="Period" id="ddlPeriod" disabled="disabled">
              <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">select period</option>
            <option value="1"> Days</option>
            <option value="2"> Week</option>
            <option value="3"> Month</option>
            <option value="4"> Year</option>
        </select>
 }
    else
    {
        <select name="Period" id="ddlPeriod"  onselect="@Model.Period" >
              <option value="0" disabled="disabled">select period</option>
             <option value="1"> Days</option>
            <option value="2"> Week</option>
            <option value="3"> Month</option>
            <option value="4"> Year</option>
        </select>
}
</div>
```

My values saved as 1 for Days ;2 for Week; 3 for Month;4 for Year.

While retrieving, it returns 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 correctly, but my dropdown only displays Days.

[image]

If I set my `Days` as `disabled="disabled"` ,then my dropdown displaying Week for whatever value it comes.

Why it is like that? Where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at the option month the /option> tag is missing the < in front . I don't know if this fixes anything but it might help. What file extension are you using for this file cause i do not think the @if code will work in a plain html file.

Comment: hi, that typo here is by mistake ,When I copy paste , I did some changes here , so missed here, In my Codes,there is no typo... and my extension is .cshtml